# Proth's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primality-test

I am trying to understand [Theorem (2.1) in this Paper.](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Ebosma/pubs/MathComp1993.pdf)
Here it is:

Let $n = h\cdot 2^k+1$ with $0<h<2^k$ and $h$ odd.
If $\left(\frac{D}{n}\right) = -1$, then:

$n$ is prime $\Leftrightarrow D^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\equiv -1 \pmod n$

But I don't see the proof, yet. Here is what I have.

It's assumed that for an element $D$ the Jacobi-Symbol $\left(\frac{D}{n}\right) = -1$.

Let $n$ be a prime. Then the Jacobisymbol is the same as the Legendresymbol.
So, by Euler's criterion I can calculate it via $\left(\frac{D}{n}\right) = D^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ and we have the right side hence $D^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod n$.

But how do I show the $\Leftarrow$ direction?
So I assumed, $n$ is not prime. Then let $n = p_1\cdot \dots\cdot p_k$ be the primce decomposition. I can then write
$\left(\frac{D}{n}\right) =-1 = \left(\frac{D}{p_1}\right)\cdot\dots\cdot\left(\frac{D}{p_k}\right)$. But I can't conclude that $D^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\not\equiv -1\pmod n$.

What am I missing?

Thanks for reading my first post, hope I wrote everything that was needed :)

Comment: **Duplicate** of  [Proth's primality criterion - understanding the common proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3316626/confusing-thing-at-the-proof-of-proth-theorem)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assume that $D^{(n-1)/2} \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$. Then in particular $D$ and $n$ are coprime.

It turns out that in this case, the Legendre symbol is a “red herring” of sorts – what’s important is the inequality on $h$.

Let $q$ be a prime dividing $n$ (so $q$ is odd), then we know that $D^{h2^{k-1}}\equiv -1 \pmod{q}$. I claim that this implies that $2^k|q-1$.

Indeed, the gcd $\omega$ of $q-1$ and $h2^k$ is such that $D^{\omega}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$. Therefore $\omega$ cannot divide $h2^{k-1}$, hence $2^k|q-1$.

Assume that $n$ isn’t prime. Then there are two prime numbers (not necessarily distinct) $p$ and $q$ such that $pq|n$. By the above, $p\geq 2^k+1$, $q \geq 2^k+1$, hence $$2^{2k}+1> h2^k+1=n \geq pq \geq (2^k+1)^2,$$ a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your time, @Aphelli. I have problems to understand the part with the gcd if $q-1$ and $h2^k$. But I am trying. Can you tell me how you come up with $D^{\omega}\equiv 1$?

Comment: You can write $\omega=s(q-1)+t(h2^k)$. Since $D^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ and $D^{h2^k} \equiv 1\pmod{q}$, $D^{\omega}=D^{s(q-1)+t(h2^k)}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.

Comment: Maybe it's too late, but why is $D^{q-1}\equiv 1$?
Sorry, I have to go home now, so I will be back here in two, three hours. Just wanted to say thank you for your time and I don't want to be rude and just leave. This forum is new for me, so, sorry if this was unnecessary information. 
I will come back and want to understand this theorem!

Comment: That $D^{q-1} \equiv 1\pmod{q}$ is  Fermat’s little theorem. Do you know about it?

Comment: Oh of course. Oh my, sorry. Will check with that knowledge in an hour

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: So, I see that $D^{\omega}\equiv 1 \pmod q$.But why does it follow that $2^k|q-1$?

Comment: If it’s not the case, then $\omega$ divides $2^{k-1}h$ (since we know it divides $2^kh$). But $D^{2^{k-1}h}\equiv -1\pmod{q}$, while $D^{\omega} \equiv 1\pmod{q}$. @BillDubuque: I confess I didn’t search for the duplicate. I will endeavor to be more careful. I believe, however, that my answer is redundant with the OP of the linked thread, not yours.

Comment: @Aphelli What matters is that essentially the same common argument is already in the linked post (and others). It doesn't matter where it occurs there (whether in the question or answers or both). Moreover, the linked post shows how it is related to other useful results, likely giving readers better intuition on the matter.

Comment: @BillDubuque this is not the same question, sorry I choose the wrong title. I am not yet familiar with this forum but i want to be. And I am not sure, is a long discussion about the topic ok? Like the one I am doing here because I miss so many points?

Comment: @mathquester It doesn't matter that the question is not (exactly) the same. Rather what matters is that you can find  answers (and more) in the linked dupe. Further, this dupe is easily located by an [obvious search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=proth+primality). We do expect questioners and answerers to search first before posting (esp. for questions on topics so common that they will surely have been treated already over the $13$ year life of the site).

Comment: @Aphelli I think I got it, thank you so much! There's still an open question for me, but I will open another thread since it will be a different topic!

Comment: @BillDubuque: I understand. Will be more cautious next time. Thank you for your advice!